# Howto find unmarked strings with gettext?

Tags: gettext

Does gettext have a way to warn me about strings that have not been wrapped in `_()` or `N_()`?

Basically is there a way to get a list of all strings that do **NOT** match the keywords used by xgettext. So, I want:

`! xgettext source_code`

Answer from the gettext mailing list:

> 1. Run xgettext once, without --extract-all, to get the normal POT file.
> 2. Run xgettext with --extract-all, to get all strings.
> 3. Run "msgcomm --less-than=2" on the two POT files, to get the difference, 
>      and see whether the output is empty.
>      You can use option --force-po    to
>      force an empty POT file even if both
>      inputs are the same.
>
> -- Bruno Haible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could compare the output with and without the `--extract-all` flag...

Comment: Thanks,I misunderstood the meaning of that option.